# To have an ajax call using javascript before window is closed in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need to make an AJAX call using javascript before window is closed in IE

```
function fun(){
    if((window.event.clientX<0) || (window.event.clientY<0)) {
      //Make the ajax call
    }
}
```

I have called the function `onload` of my webpage, it is working fine for browser having single tab but failing for browser having multiple tabs.

I have also tried calling

```
onbeforeunload="function callAjax();"
```

in `<body>`. But it also calling at the time when I am using

```
window.close()
```

to close popups.

PS: I don't want to use jQuery.

Comment: If you want to call any function when IE browser closed - it's not posible. If you want to call function when tab with your site page closed or when your site page  reloaded|unloaded (without closing tab) you can use `onbeforeunload` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or `onunload` event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536973%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @Andrew : Thanks for the help. <pre>Below is the requirement <pre>I have around 350 pages in my apps which these needs to be implemented.    Solution    1. I will create a page tool.js containing the ajax call    2. I will call my `tools.js` as below `<script type="text/javascript" for="window" src="tools.js" event="onunload">` as shown in the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536973%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Will it works..

Answer (score 1):

Wow thanks @Andrew it works  I have created multiple pages as the below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <TITLE> New Document 3 </TITLE>
  <script type="text/javascript" for="window" src="tools.js" event="onunload"/>
  <META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="EditPlus">
  <META NAME="Author" CONTENT="">
  <META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
  <META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">
 </HEAD>

 <BODY>

 </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Created a tools.js

```
alert('I am getting closed yipeeee');
```

Whenever I am closing the window actually tools.js is being called for all the pages

Minimum changes required ie

```
<script type="text/javascript" for="window" src="tools.js" event="onunload"/>
```

Thanks for the help.